# Can a D.O. sign the medical certificate for a student visa at the Chicago consulate?

Tags: visas, spain, consulates, chicago

I am applying for a student visa at the Chicago Consulate and it says a medical doctor must sign it. However, I visited a D.O. and I was wondering if anyone had successfully applied for a student visa with a D.O. signing the medical certificate

Comment: The Chicago Consulate? Of what country? What is a D.O.?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: [Doctor of Osteopathic Medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Osteopathic_Medicine). Apparently they're officially considered medical practitioners in the US, but the authorities of some other countries might regard them as a kind of alternative medicine on the level of acupuncturist or reflexologists.

Comment: @HenningMakholm A modern DO in the US comes from a parallel medical education system intended to produce more physicians at a lower cost. Generally DO schools are lesser known, easier to get into. They work (with exceptions) largely in primary care/family medicine, due to the focus of DO residency programs, and their training and rights are essentially equivalent to MDs. The osteopathic stuff is rarely practiced.